# Add a line in file with awk called from bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have this file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

and I want to use awk to add a line after/before the pattern `127.0.0.1`.
Pattern and line are bash variables.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="test.txt"
pattern='127.0.0.1'
line='127.0.1.1   cent.centurian.com   centurian'

awk -vpattern="$pattern" -vline="$line" '/pattern/{print;print line;next}1' "$file"
```

Doesn't work...

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is simpler:

```
sed "/$pattern/a\
$line" "$file"
```

Output:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   cent.centurian.com   centurian

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

---

*GNU* `sed` allows a one-liner version of the above:

```
sed $file -e "/$pattern/a $line"
```

...and to output `$line` *before* `$pattern`, change the `a`*(ppend)* to an `i`*(nsert)*:

```
sed $file -e "/$pattern/i $line"
```

Answer (score 1):

Close. That looks for the (literal) pattern `pattern`.

You need to use `$0 ~ pattern` to match against a variable.

```
$ pattern='127.0.0.1'
$ line='127.0.1.1   cent.centurian.com   centurian'
$ awk -vpattern="$pattern" -vline="$line" '$0 ~ pattern {print; print line; next} 1' $file | head -2
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   cent.centurian.com   centurian
```

Comment: OK, worked! Also I used $file instead of hosts as in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just made a function that do this:

```
################################################################################
## Adds a line in a file.                                                     ##
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Given the arguments:                                                         #
# 1st: file                                                                    #
# 2nd: string to find                                                          #
# 3rd: line to add                                                             #
# 4th: 'b' for before, 'a' for after.                                          #
# It adds a line before or after the line containing the search string.        #
################################################################################
function addLineInFileOnString() {
   local file pattern line where tmp
   file="$1"
   pattern="$2"
   line="$3"
   where="$4"
   tmp="$( cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1 )"
   tmp='tmp.'$tmp

   if [[ $where == 'b' ]]; then
      awk -v pattern="$pattern" -v line="$line" '$0 ~ pattern {print line; print; next} 1' "$file" | tee 1>/dev/null $tmp
   elif [[ $where == 'a' ]]; then
      awk -v pattern="$pattern" -v line="$line" '$0 ~ pattern {print; print line; next} 1' "$file" | tee 1>/dev/null $tmp
   fi

   [[ -e $tmp ]] && cp "$tmp" "$file" && rm "$tmp"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the matched line:

```
awk -v line='127.0.1.1   cent.centurian.com   centurian' '/127\.0\.0\.1/ \
        { printf "%s\n%s\n", line, $0; next }; 1' file.txt
```

After the matched line:

```
awk -v line='127.0.1.1   cent.centurian.com   centurian' '/127\.0\.0\.1/ \
        { printf "%s\n%s\n", $0, line; next }; 1' file.txt
```

---

- `/127\.0\.0\.1/` matches the pattern
- If the pattern is matched, the desired formatted output is printed by `printf` based on whether the variable `line` would be before or after the matched line

---

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt                                                                                                              
127.0.0.1   localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

$ awk -v line='127.0.1.1   cent.centurian.com   centurian' '/127\.0\.0\.1/ { printf "%s\n%s\n", $0, line; next }; 1' file.txt
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   cent.centurian.com   centurian

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

$ awk -v line='127.0.1.1   cent.centurian.com   centurian' '/127\.0\.0\.1/ { printf "%s\n%s\n", line, $0; next }; 1' file.txt
127.0.1.1   cent.centurian.com   centurian
127.0.0.1   localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: OK worked! But I changed as: awk -vline="$line" '/127\.0\.0\.1/ { printf "%s\n%s\n", $0, line; next }; 1' $file as per question. But I want '127.0.0.1' to be a bash variable!